# How to Access One Liquid Associative Array Key

Tags: associative-array, jekyll, liquid

I can only find information about looping over associative arrays. However I want to access only the `group` key of the following `lesson` associative array to extract its value into my page.   I've tried a number of syntaxes including dot notation: `<li>{{ node.lesson.group }}</li>` but that returns blank.  I know the lesson associative array is present because when I use the syntax `<li>{{ node.lesson }}</li>` I get the output `{"group"=>"intros", "position"=>1}`

Following is an example of the front matter.

```
---
layout: page
title: "Control Structures 1"
lesson: 
 - 
  group: 'intros'
  position: 1
---
{% include JB/setup %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one answer to the problem by using a `map`filter.  Can anybody do better than this because it seems quite wordy.

`<li>{{ node.lesson | map: 'group' }}</li>`

*(Note: It never fails - after 1 hour of trying various things I discover the answer minutes after posting the question.)*